# JPanel not displaying Graphics

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, java-2d

I have a java class that extends from JPanel. The basic purpose of extending this class from JPanel is that i want to draw some graphical figures inside this JPanel. The code of this class is as follow:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
public class ObjectViewer extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        //just for testing
        g.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 10);

        g.drawLine(150, 150, 250, 150);
    }
}
```

Now i am loading this JPanel in JScrollPane, by using the following code.

```
JPanel jpnl = new ObjectViewer();
jScrollPane2.add(jpnl);//Note: I drag and drop this JScrollPanel at desired location from NetBeans gui.
```

But i am unable to see any graphics (Rect and Line) in that JScrollPane, any suggestions for what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Does it work without the JScrollPane?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never add your JPanel directly to a JScrollPane but rather to its viewport. So for instance, not

```
jScrollPane2.add(jpnl);
```

but rather something like:

```
jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jpnl);
```

or

```
jScrollPane2.getViewport().add(jpnl);
```

alternatively, you could add the JPanel as a parameter in the scrollpane's constructor.

Comment: nitpicking (the answer is correct, of course, +1 :-) - I would prefer you to not recommend calling a method on a contained component when there's a delegate method: conceptually, that's breaking encapsulation without need